# Building a simple login page using MongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, html, mongodb

I am trying to connect my login page to Mongodb but i am encountering some error.Since I am trying it for the first time I am not completely familiar to this.I would like to know where I have gone wrong
 This is the html page

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
User Name:
 <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
 Password:
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is PHP code:

```
    <html>
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])
  {
   $username = ($_POST['username']);
  $password = ($_POST['password']);
    if(empty($username))
    {
     echo "Empty or invalid email address";
    }
     if(empty($password)){
     echo "Enter your password"; 
      }
      $con = new MongoClient();
     // Select Database
     if($con)
      {
      $db = $con->tickets;
      // Select Collection
    $collection = $db->Admin;
     $qry = array("username" => $username,"password" => md5($password));
      $result = $collection->findOne($qry);
    if($result){
     echo "You are successully loggedIn";
       }
    else
     { echo "unsuccessful";
     }

      } else { 
      die("Mongo DB not connected");
      } 
        }
      ?>
       </html>
```

Comment: what 'some error' are you getting?

Comment: its showing unsuccessful even though the data is present in the database. I am able to retrieve the username and password in other php program. I think it is not quering properly. I would like to know where i have gone wrong.

Comment: after the query check what error you get with `var_dump($mongo->lastError());`

Comment: I have not used $mongo variable anywhere in the code. it shows undefined variable

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specific that would make it end just before `ticket`. So I don't think there is an exact answer that can be given.

However in cases like this, try narrow it down to a smaller problem, for example, does this work:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "Hello";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If no, then you probably don't have PHP installed correctly or possibly not configured correctly.

If yes, build it up a tad:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo $_POST['submitForm'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Etc, etc

As a side note, I am not encouraging the mix of PHP/HTML nor the direct use of $_POST - I am just building on the original question

Comment: Php is working fine. Moreover it is connecting to Database. I am able to insert using php. Just this login is not working

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use empty function on the `$result`.

So your php code must be like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = ($_POST['username']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
    $pass_hash = md5($password);
    if(empty($username)){
        die("Empty or invalid email address");
    }
    if(empty($password)){
        die("Enter your password");
    }
    $con = new MongoClient();
    // Select Database
    if($con){
        $db = $con->tickets;
        // Select Collection
        $collection = $db->admin;   // you may use 'admin' instead of 'Admin'
        $qry = array("username" => $username, "password" => $pass_hash);
        $result = $collection->findOne($qry);

        if(!empty($result)){
            echo "You are successfully loggedIn";
        }else{
            echo "Wrong combination of username and password";
        }
    }else{
        die("Mongo DB not connected!");
    }
}
?>
```

Also check your collection name. Is that 'admin' or 'Admin'

Hope this will help.

Comment: The code is working fine but its giving unsuccessful login even though the username and password is stored in DB. Is there any other method to compare username and password? @Paras

Comment: are you sure your collection name is 'Admin'? because usually collection names do not contain capital letters.
I tries the code on my PC and it seems to work file. @Shraddha

Comment: I changed the collection name as admin but still showing unsuccessful login

Comment: you are using **not** empty function write? If it does not work  may be there is some typo error.

Answer (score 0):

I Used same code but the unsuccessful login  error occurs for me and I fixed it.hope it will be helpful!

try this

`$result = $collection->findOne(array('username' =>'$username,'password' =>md5($password)));`

Instead of

```
$qry = array("username" => $username,"password" => md5($password));
$result = $collection->findOne($qry);
```